# Windows Virus & Threat Protection is not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, virus

Recently I format my laptop and reinstall windows 10 pro.

Initially the windows defender was working well. but later when I opened the Windows Security I noticed that the 'Virus and Threat Protection' is not working. When I restart the service, it gives the following error.

[image: Screenshot of the windows security giving error]

Even my windows update and medic services also working fine.

[image: Screenshot of the windows services]

Please somebody know the reason for this?

Comment: What build of Windows? What patch level? Are there messages in the Event Viewer that may shed light on things? What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Recently I format my laptop and reinstall windows 10 pro.

That should be the most recent version of Windows or very close to it.

Do the following:

1. Update Windows:   Start, Settings, Update and Security.  Run Updates and look for Optional Updates and do these.  Restart after.
2. In the event something did not go precisely right during the first reinstall, run DISM and SFC.

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

After all the above, Windows Defender should be properly working.